# How to turn an object in Django into the corresponding "select_for_update()" object?

Tags: django

Is there a shorter way to achieve

```
to_update = models.Person.objects.select_for_update().get(pk=instance.pk)
```

e.g., in:

```
def UpdateAge(instance, new_age):
    with transaction.atomic():
        to_update = models.Person.objects.select_for_update().get(pk=instance.pk)
        to_update.age = new_age
        to_update.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to shorten that would be to follow standard practice & import your model so do something like;

```
from myapp.models import Person


def UpdateAge(instance, new_age):
    with transaction.atomic():
        to_update = Person.objects.select_for_update().get(
            pk=instance.pk
        )
        to_update.age = new_age
        to_update.save()
```

Here are the docs on [`select_for_update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update)

Comment: I see. I was expecting there is a instance.select_for_update(). Thanks!

Comment: @Irvan these things aren't at the instance level, it's class/table level as it's happening to the database query